# How to remove custom icons from launcher

Tags: launcher, .desktop, evince

I was trying to add a custom desktop icon for evince (installed using flatpak) in my launcher. First I experimented with nautilus; I created this `test.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=My script
Exec=nautilus
Type=Application
```

I moved this to `.local/share/applications` and used `sudo desktop-file-install test.desktop` and it worked as expected.
Now I renamed this file to `custom_evince.desktop` and modified the script as;

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Evince
Exec=flatpak run org.gnome.Evince
Type=Application
```

Followed the same procedure as before and it also worked as expected.

**Issue**:  My initial icon `My script` is still there (and is functional) in the launcher and I don't want it there. How to remove `My script` but keep `Evince`

[image: Attached is the screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have choosen to use `sudo desktop-file-install test.desktop`. That command does do nothing else than to copy a .desktop launcher to a system wide location where it will be picked up in the menu. So just delete the copy in `/usr/share/applications`.

There is no need to run `desktop-file-install`. Just keep your `.desktop` launcher in `~/.local/share/applications` if only that user needs to see it, or in `/usr/local/share/applications` if it must be available for all users. The `desktop-file-install` tool is rather intended for packagers. Launchers for apps installed using the package manager end up in `/usr/share/applications`.